# Timesheet.js not initiating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm struggling to get Timesheet.js working, I initially wanted it on a Wordpress site but had no luck so stripped it back completely to a plain html file. Here's my code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="timesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="timesheet.js" type="text/javascript" /></script>

<script type="text/javascript">     
new Timesheet('timesheet', 2002, 2013, [
  ['2002', '09/2002', 'A freaking awesome time', 'lorem'],
  ['06/2002', '09/2003', 'Some great memories', 'ipsum'],
  ['2003', 'Had very bad luck'],
  ['10/2003', '2006', 'At least had fun', 'dolor'],
  ['02/2005', '05/2006', 'Enjoyed those times as well', 'ipsum'],
  ['07/2005', '09/2005', 'Bad luck again', 'default'],
  ['10/2005', '2008', 'For a long time nothing happened', 'dolor'],
  ['01/2008', '05/2009', 'LOST Season #4', 'lorem'],
  ['01/2009', '05/2009', 'LOST Season #4', 'lorem'],
  ['02/2010', '05/2010', 'LOST Season #5', 'lorem'],
  ['09/2008', '06/2010', 'FRINGE #1 & #2', 'ipsum']
]);
</script>

<div id="timesheet" class="timesheet color-scheme-default"></div>
```

This is the [page](http://dev.elrha.org/test.html) I've tried it on. Pretty sure it's a problem with the [supplied files](http://js-tutorial.com/timesheetjs-simple-html5-css3-time-sheets-1138) and not something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try keeping your script inside document.ready function

Comment: @ShamanthSundaram That worked, thanks. Post as an answer and I'll ok it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the DOM is not ready when you are running your code. You could do few things:

Move this code:

```
<div id="timesheet" class="timesheet color-scheme-default"></div>
```

above your:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    new Timesheet(...);
</script>
```

Or wrap your code in `jQuery(document).ready(function () { ... });` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {     
    new Timesheet(...);
});
</script>
```